# binding vscode profiles to a workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code

The new version of VSCode 1.75 contains the new feature `Profiles`, which can be accessed via `[Settings-Wheel]`-`[profiles]`.

One can now create profiles with different extensions and switch between them.
It would be great if a workspace would automatically use a specific profile.
Is there any way to bind the profiles to a workspace/working directory so that I can set up a workspace to automatically select a specific profile when I open that workspace?
So far I have not found a way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it turns out, VSCode does this already. You just have to follow the correct order:

You select a specific workspace / folder and set your profile there the way you want it to be for that workspace - I take a workspace for C++ and uninstall everything I don't need for C++ development.

Now you can choose another workspace - for example one for Python. I create a new profile (I like to use one based on my base profile where I had everything installed so far) and remove everything from it that I don't need for Python development - for example the C/C++ development tools.

If I now switch back to my C++ workspace, I find all the settings there again as I left them.

The nice thing is that I don't just deactivate extensions as before - I actually uninstall them from the profile.
It makes the Extensions area much cleaner.

Comment: have you seen if it is possible to save profile into that folder? it forgot when I moved the folder.

Comment: It seems not to be stored inside the folder but in somewhere in the settings folders, so it's lost when you move a folder.
But then, selecting the correct profile once again after moving a folder is not such a big deal unless you have to move a certain folder regulary to always different places.

Comment: I made regular "system reinstall" :)) so lots of folders to do such action. I hope there is already a way we missed or they add in near future (like keeping it in ".vscode" folder). Maybe we need to request if it does not exist. I am too lazy to check for the moment ;) thanks for this Q&A to keep heads up